# mv within shell script does not move files

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

Often discussed, yet the answers did not get me to a solution unfortunately, and I am a bit ashamed that I need to ask this question again. But, here we are.

I have a shell script `dosomething.sh` with the shebang `#!/bin/bash`.

Within this script I have the following line to copy files of a certain type from one directory to another:

```
find "/var/www/analysis_xyz/" -name '*log.gz' -exec mv -f {} "/media/pi/MOBIDICDATA" \;
```

When the script is executed, nothing is copied. I am positive that this is only a minor thing I am missing. The question is: what?

---

The question itself may appear broad, but please note I have posted my own answer that solves the issue. I think there's enough educational value in this case study to make it useful for the community.

Comment: Is this the literal code used in the script, i.e. no variable expansion, control structures etc.?

Comment: Perhaps this line is never executed.   Add a `set -x` to the beginning of your script and see if it is.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I will try this...

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Thanks for the hint! I did not know that if I add a set -x I will actually see the output. I will answer with what was wrong.

Comment: I have edited the previous answer.

Comment: After reading your expanded answer, I think the original line would have worked for read-write mount. Therefore the statement `When I execute this line directly in the CLI, everything works like a charm. Unfortunately, when the script is executed, nothing is copied.` looks like some kind of misunderstanding. I'm going to edit the question and the answer to make them a case study that could be useful for future users with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment-posters, I have been able to resolve the issue. This is an edited version of my previous answer because it was found to be not sufficient at all and raised more questions than it answered.

So here I am trying to describe every problem that led to the issue itself and how I resolved it.

---

#### Attempt #1: – Wrong `mv` syntax?

From the script, the following line did nothing:

```
find "/var/www/analysis_xyz/" -name '*log.gz' -exec mv -f {} "/media/pi/MOBIDICDATA" \;
```

I was not sure if I could use the standard parameters of `mv` while calling it from an `-exec`, but I added the `-f` parameter to overwrite existing files in the target directory anyway.

By adding the `set -x` to the script as suggested, it gave me an error message back saying something is wrong with the arguments of the `mv` command. So I removed the `-f` parameter. With no success. After googling a bit further and seeing some examples that all used the `-t` parameter, so I added it. Again, no success, instead I got an error message saying, that a directory is expected which I interpreted wrong (sorry, a bit of a noob regarding shell scripting). At this moment I had the following syntax, which turned out later was absolutely correct and working:

```
find /var/www/analysis_xyz/ -name '*log.gz' -exec mv {} -t /media/pi/MOBIDICDATA \;
```

(notice the moved `{}`). But at the moment the issue was still unresolved and I wasn't even sure if `-f` and `-t` were parts of it.

---

#### Attempt #2: – Am I trying to write to a read-only mounted USB-stick?

As you may have noticed, the target-folder is `/media/pi/…` So you might be aware that I am using a Raspberry Pi and am on Raspbian. The USB Stick I wanted to write the data to is mounted automatically to this folder (as long as the device is named `MOBIDICDATA`. The automatic mount mounted the device as read-only (and at this moment I had no idea why). This caused the process to be executed, but no files were copied and an error message was raised saying the device was read-only.

I decided to not rely on the automatic mount and mount the device myself on reboot to another location. New target was `/mobidicdata`. The device was mounted successfully, but still was read-only for some reason.

---

#### Attempt #3: – Is life to short to remove USB safely?

In the past I literally killed 2 USB devices by removing them safely from a windows PC so I decided to not do this anymore, since I never killed a device by just pulling it out. Little did I know that e.g. USB sticks, that have simply been pulled out *always* get mounted as read-only on most non-Windows systems; which makes complete sense since the filesystem might be corrupted and lead to other problems. After learning this, I removed the USB device safely, mounted it, and now it was r/w.

So, test again with writable device and the following syntax:

```
find /var/www/analysis_xyz/ -name '*log.gz' -exec mv {} -t /mobidicdata \;
```

…which was working.

For me this was a little bit of an Odysee.

---

#### Summary

Yes, the `-t`/`-f` parameter was not the problem as mentioned earlier. It was more of a multiple-problem-cluster that I should have described in more detail earlier already.

I hope to have shed some light on the whole thing and what I know from now and will do in the future:

- You definitely should remove USB safely

Unfortunately I am not able to completely reproduce the problem above. In this case I could have stated the exact error-messages. But I still think that this gives a little more insight in what happened and what was done.

Comment: Strange, I don't understand why the -f would cause the mv to fail.  If that was so, then there would have been error messages.  You didn't end that line with a `2>/dev/null` by any chance?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski moreover, just replacing the "-f" by a "-t" should have created an error: the "-t" should be followed by the directory name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I will explain further details tomorrow when I am back in the office.

Comment: Okay, now for some further details. Turned out, it indeed was not that easy as described in the answer, because there were multiple problems which led to the rather strange behavior. So I'll post another answer describing exactly what I have done and what the problem was.

Comment: `-t` argument of `mv` is useful for at least two reasons: (1) It tells `mv` the target path must be a directory, not a filename. Compare `mv a b`, `mv a -t b` and `mv a b/` when `a` exists and `b` does not. (2) It allows you to use `find … -exec mv -t … {} +` syntax which can move *many* files with a single `mv` process but requires `{}` to be just before terminating `+`, so the usual `mv` syntax (where target directory is the last argument) cannot be used.